# Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 5

Tags: php, regex, apache

As i mentioned in title i am getting the error of *Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed:* which is really weird for me;

actually on the VPS of godaddy i moved my site; first i got an error of GD library; so i installed GD library by using easy apache from WHM, 
then now when i m trying to run my website i am getting this warning,  `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 5` on this page **techchef.org/development/module/newsfeed/LoadDataFromFeed.php**

however the same script runs on my another server which is **techchef.org/development/module/newsfeed/LoadDataFromFeed.php** and it works fine

here is the script i am not sure if it is because of apache settings, if yes then what actually i missed.

Below is the php script for which it mentioned the error

```
$str= strtolower($str);
      $str= preg_replace("/(à|á|?|?|ã|â|?|?|?|?|?|a|?|?|?|?|?)/","a",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(è|é|?|?|?|ê|??|?|?|?|?)/","e",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(ì|í|?|?|i)/","i",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(ò|ó|??|??|õ|ô|?|?|?|?|?|o|??|?|?|?|?)/","o",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(ù|ú|?|?|u|u|?|?|?|?|?)/","u",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(?|ý|?|?|?)/","y",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(d)/","d",$str);  
      $str= preg_replace("/(!|@|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\<|\>|\?|\/|,|\.|\:|\;|\'| |\"|\&|\#|\[|\]|~|$|_)/","-",$str); 
      $str= preg_replace("/(-+-)/","-",$str); 
      $str= preg_replace("/(^\-+|\-+$)/","",$str); 
      $str= preg_replace("/(-)/"," ",$str);
```

Comment: Don't know what the problem is but that code screams refactoring. What  are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Try commenting out everything and then uncomment lines one by one to figure out which one exactly is breaking

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Why are you using all these question mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you copied the code from wherever you've munged the formatting/encoding.

```
$str= preg_replace("/(à|á|?|?|ã|â|?|?|?|?|?|a|?|?|?|?|?)/","a",$str);
                       // ^- offset 5
```

Educated guess, this [and all the other question marks] should be another `a`-like character, and not a question mark. `?` is a metacharacter to do with repetition [0 or 1] and should be escaped for a literal `?`.

Same goes for the other expressions.